# Change the state of a prop of a single component which is also in another components react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two components which are

```
<EnemyHand key={2} player_money={playerMoney} />
<EnemyHand key={3} player_money={playerMoney} />
```

```
const [playerMoney, setPlayerMoney] = useState(0);

function updatePlayerMoney() {
    setPlayerMoney(playerMoney + 10);
}

<button onClick={updatePlayerMoney}>money + 10</button>
```

---

Now i want to change the value of **playerMoney** from the the component with key=3

As an example: The default value = 0. Now the second Enemy gets 100 $. How can i achieve that?

The EnemyHand component looks like this:

```
<span className="money-display d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          {player_money ? player_money : 0} <span> €</span>
</span>
```

---

I tried to access it by using the `key` attribute or by `document.getElementByID` but this doesnt work. Maybe i am wrong using the `useState`.

Comment: If you're trying to use a single `playerMoney` state to each player so you'll need to set this state as an array or object and update only desired player data inside it. In single state when you update it's value it will be reflected on every component using it's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the same state for both. You can:

- create multiple states for each player
- use an array or object in the state

```
const [playersMoney, setPlayersMoney] = useState({leo: 10, salah: 25, ...})
// or
const [playersMoney, setPlayersMoney] = useState([{id: 1, money: 10}, {id: 2, money: 25}])

// with object
<EnemyHand key={1} player_money={playersMoney.leo} />
// with Array
{playersMoney.map(player => (
  <EnemyHand key={player.id} player_money={player.money} />
))}

// You function should be refactored to:
// with object:
function updatePlayerMoney(playerName) {
    setPlayerMoney(previousValue => {
      return {
        ...previousValue,
        [playerName]: previousValue[playerName] + 10
      }
    });
}

// with array
function updatePlayerMoney(playerId) {
    setPlayerMoney(previousValue => {
      return previousValue.map(player => {
        if (player.id === playerId) return player.money + 10
        return player.money
      })
    });
}
```

Comment: thx this could be my solution. Now i need to figure out how i go on with my work. Your example has some variable mistakes but i think i got the point :)